# Tabu or tabulongtable multicolumns

Tags: columns, tabu, longtabu

I want to use one of the `tabu` or `tabulongtable` environments to make a table where the middle two columns are matched in the first row.

Now what I could do is this, which compiles but doesn't match the columns

```
{
\begin{tabu}{|X|X|X|X|} \tabucline-
\multicolumn2{|c|}{hello} &2&3\\ \hline
\tabucline-
\tabuphantomline
1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
\end{tabu}
}
```

I tried something like this, but it didn't work:

```
 {\begin{tabu}{|X|X|X[2]|X|} \tabucline-
1&2&3&4 \\ \hline
d&3
\multicolumn2{|c|}{hello} \\ 
\tabucline-
\tabuphantomline
\end{tabu}
}
```

This code has errors; can you explain what I did wrong / how I have to do it right?

Comment: your examples would be clearer if they were complete documents that reproduced any errors. Also the title asks about multirow but the fragments use \multicolumn which do you mean?

Comment: in the second one you are missing a `&` after `3`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `&` after `3`.

Also, unrelated, but you should remove the `{`...`}` around the environment.